# Django Queryset counting number of rows based on aggregated field condition

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have following model:

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    cost = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    ...
```

I need to return amount of purchases for each day, with cost that exceeded its average cost of purchases for this day.

i tried using:

```
Purchase.objects.values('date').annotate(
    avg_cost=Avg('cost', output_field=FloatField()
).annotate(
    purchases_above=Sum(
        Case(
            When(cost__gt=F('avg_cost'), then=1), 
            default=0, 
            output_field=IntegerField()
        )
    )
)
```

but i get error

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot compute Count('<Case: CASE WHEN <Q: (AND: ('cost__gt', F(avg_cost)))> THEN Value(1), ELSE Value(0)>'): '<Case: CASE WHEN <Q: (AND: ('cost__gt', F(avg_cost)))> THEN Value(1), ELSE Value(0)>' is an aggregate
```

I am doing something wrong? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `filter` argument to the `Sum` function:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Purchase.objects.values('date').annotate(
    avg_cost=Avg('cost', output_field=FloatField()
).annotate(
    purchases_above=Sum("cost", filter=Q(F("cost") > F("avg_cost")))
)
```

However, when combining multiple annotations, expect to get wrong results. See the [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations)